# How to troubleshoot a memory leak in tomcat applications

Tags: memory, java, tomcat, memory-leaks

We have a tomcat server serving several web applications. With jconsole I can see that the heap memory grows over time. We had some crashs with an OutOfMemoryError for the heap memory after about one day.
Platform: SLES 12 SP3, Tomcat 8

Is it possible to determine which of our web applications is causing a memory leak with a tool?

Comment: This may be a better question for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27885777/9465588) JVM doesn't provide such information, however, Tomcat F.A.Q. states that

> That being said, a memory profiling tool might prove the above statements wrong - but you probably don't want to use them in a production environment.

I'm no expert in Java,  however I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/385210/9465588) for you. They talk about [Oracle JRockit Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/overview/index-090630.html)

It is not an easy task anyway, JRMC will give you the memory usage of every class in the system. If you have common clases between your projects (like dependencies) it will not be easy to determine which project one is causing the issue, although maybe a simple update will fix your issue in that case.

Another answer in the same questions suggests to use an IDE (Netbeans) in order to debug projects separately.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51027242/9465588) explains [glowroot](https://glowroot.org/), another Java profiling tool which you can directly attach to Tomcat. [This is an example](https://demo.glowroot.org/jvm/heap-histogram) histogram output.

If the issue only happens in production be carefull using profiling tools, they tend to REALLY slow things down. Have you considered that the issue may be caused by Tomcat? Do you have the latest packages available for your distro installed?

Comment: Thank's a lot. I will try your suggestions!